# Java read/write BufferedImage performance from file vs memory

Tags: java, image

I have a http client that gets a json response containing a png image string that I then rotate.

Everything works as expected but I was curious to know why (METHOD 1) saving the http response image in memory as a BufferedImage before rotating said BufferdImage is slower than (METHOD 2) saving the http response image to a file and then reading that file to a BufferedImage before rotating the same BufferedImage?

This is counter to what we all know that doing like for like read/writes in memory are faster than file i/o. My laptop that the java is running on has abundant memory and disk space.

```
////////////METHOD 1 - WRITE/READ IMAGE FROM MEMORY
log.info("START TEST1 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
OutputStream outputStream = null;
byte[] imageByteArray = 
    Base64.decodeBase64(jsonObj.getString("LabelImages"));

//Convert byte array back to BufferedImage
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

BufferedImage rotatedImg = rotate(img, 90);
File outputfile = new File("/var/opt/DI/tmp/rotatedlabel" + orderId + ".png");
ImageIO.write(rotatedImg, "png", outputfile);
log.info("END TEST1 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

////////////METHOD 2 - WRITE/READ IMAGE FROM FILE
log.info("START TEST2 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
writeImageStringToFile(jsonObj.getString("LabelImages"), orderId);
BufferedImage rotatedImg2 = rotate(ImageIO.read(new 
File("/var/opt/DI/tmp/label" + orderId + ".png")), 90);
File outputfile2 = new 
File("/var/opt/openbravo/bluecrest/DI/tmp/rotatedlabel" + orderId + ".png");
ImageIO.write(rotatedImg2, "png", outputfile2);
log.info("END TEST2 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

METHOD 2 is about 10% faster than METHOD 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us how you did your performance test. If you do it as written here (call method 1 then method 2 in the same program), my guess is that it's due to the JIT optimizing the rotate method during method1, and enjoying that optimization during method2, to the point where it overcomes disk operations.

Personally, when I do performance comparison tests, I run method1 like 10 times in a program, eliminate the two or three worst results, then do the same with method2 in a separate program. This usually gives enough time to the JIT to kick in and gives more meaningful numbers..